# How to expand People Search Result (rest api)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, rest

now:

a) if `query == "Popov"`, i get 3 items

b) if `query == "Popova"` i get 1 items

I wish on `query =="Popov"` get 4 items: sum a) + b)

how can I customize rest search ?

```
url: "_api/search/query?querytext='query'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the the wildcard operator (*)

So `query == "Popov*"` would give you the wished result

Reference: [Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558911.aspx)